# Devices on Network Intermittently Unable to Ping Each Other

Tags: networking, ssh, ping, icmp

I'm trying to connect to an NVIDIA Jetson AGX Orin DevKit (Ubuntu 20.04) over my local network. I believe that I've set up the SSH server correctly because sometimes I'm able to connect to it. However, sometimes I also cannot connect to it. When I ping the device, sometimes I get a response, sometimes the request sometimes out, sometimes the host is down. There does not seem to be a pattern either. Both devices are connected to the network, on the same subnet and same gateway. Both devices have firewalls disabled, as does the router (temporarily). Device isolation is also turned off. I've tried connecting to it from an Ubuntu 20.04 laptop, Mac, and Windows 10 as well, with no differences. I have a feeling it has something to do with the network or router itself because sometimes other devices aren't able to ping each other over my network as well, but I can't pin down what exactly is happening and it's driving me insane. Has anyone come across this?

Comment: Someone just asked a very similar question. https://superuser.com/questions/1728413/two-devices-on-same-wifi-network-unable-to-see-each-other-unless-arp-table-set-m

Comment: @Spiff Thanks! I'll check that out. What a coincidence